# Unable to capture the whole screen of a web page

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to capture a screenshot of a web page (maximize mode). Below is the code in C#.net

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot) driver).GetScreenshot();

string screenshot = ss.AsBase64EncodedString;
byte[] screenshotAsByteArray = ss.AsByteArray;

ss.SaveAsFile(FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
ss.ToString();
```

It was able to capture the web page but the issue is that, its like it resizes the web page (although the web page is in window.Maximize) then take the screenshot. I need to capture the whole screen of the web page. Can anyone help me one this?

Comment: You have to manually scroll it and piece it together.

Comment: there is no scrollbar on the web page, all the data i needed is in the page, i just need to capture the whole screen. My issue is that, its like its changing the window size (1/4 of the original size) before capturing the screen

Comment: @user3492409, have you tried plugging in an artificial wait (i.e. `Thread.Sleep(1000)`) after maximizing the window? I'm not confident that `Window.Maximize()` runs synchronously.

Comment: it seems like there is an issue on IEdriver when getting the screenshot ["browser window should not get resized when capture a screenshot from IE browser"](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5332), the IE browser is getting resize before making the screenshot

Comment: i'm still looking for a solution or any workaround for this isue